# How to avoid Map of Map of Map of Map in Avro schema

Tags: java, hadoop, avro, bigdata

There is a requirement for defining Avro Schema for Map of Map of Map of Map (4 level nested map) in my application. I am using keys at every level except the last map (final inner map). I would like to know what are the pros and cons of the schema. Is there any problem with performance?

Comment: Impossible to answer. It depends on the data. A 4-level map is not necessarily a problem if it is strictly necessary, though I suspect it isn't.

Comment: what about the performance of the application?

Answer (score 0):

Always avoid using nested maps.

AVRO file format is schema based. If you use nested map it will become difficult to design a schema. Also avro works based on serialisation technique. If you are going to work with "String" it will work fine but not with the case of other data types.

Comment: There is no problem with schema design. I already designed the schema. But I want to know pros and cons of this

Comment: It is a performance compromise. Everytime during deserialisation complete object will be recreated. If you use nested map, think how hard it is to recreate the same map.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the choice of your Schema Map>> it means for a given key you have lot of values.

This is a classical case when you should start looking for Columnar data storage like parquet.

Mix AVRO with parquet and flatten out the Avro schema.

As parquet is Columnar data format , it will not store the repeated data multiple times, but only once.

With use of ORC you will end up with a simple schema for AVRO

http://bytepadding.com/big-data/spark/read-write-parquet-files-using-spark/